# What is | in diff output?

Tags: diff

I am diff'ing two .md5 files with `diff -yb --suppress-common-lines --width=250`
and getting

```
0b92397d4978b7b5ba1ae2d4be0ca639    1.__Ms._Eldoris_McCondichie_3-5-04-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_material_copy    |   66c0a190ccf79e6ca1e34b86bfe89788    1.  Ms. Eldoris McCondichie 3:5:04.mov
66c0a190ccf79e6ca1e34b86bfe89788    1.__Ms._Eldoris_McCondichie_3-5-04.mov                          |   7519e0c6d5f8f56be15b5c6eb82f1678  10. Mr. Clyde Eddy.mov
9ca5150c4f399ad58aae1e4a4a97f809    10._Mr._Clyde_Eddy-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_material_copy.mov            |   1eedc2c35fdbbc033dbc7bea8b3e4c0d  11. Ms. Jewel Smitherman Rogers 1a w TC.mov
7519e0c6d5f8f56be15b5c6eb82f1678    10._Mr._Clyde_Eddy.mov                                  |   535acdb76a8f56f50bad418c8ff18ec7  12. Ms. Jewel Smitherman Rogers 1b w TC.mov
11411fac492a50e7692669849281dd8a    11._Ms._Jewel_Smitherman_Rogers_1a_w_TC-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_material    |   2f5d941751409dfd407e8f181aa745c6  13. Ms. Jewel Smitherman Rogers 2 w TC.mov
1eedc2c35fdbbc033dbc7bea8b3e4c0d    11._Ms._Jewel_Smitherman_Rogers_1a_w_TC.mov                         |   4a0c342444fedb2096c8495fae5e1459  14. Ms. Thelma Knight w TC.mov
acf43bd1b507f1370238dd9d7855f177    12._Ms._Jewel_Smitherman_Rogers_1b_w_TC-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_material    |   56b0d7952f01b48f47d90a5c300411ef  15. Mr. Robert Holloway w TC.mov
535acdb76a8f56f50bad418c8ff18ec7    12._Ms._Jewel_Smitherman_Rogers_1b_w_TC.mov                         |   3117d375927b0032f7b804d1f272f97a  16. Mr. Archie Franklin w TC.mov
1e2c9a47ef1ae1869e35e1c439af054f    13._Ms._Jewel_Smitherman_Rogers_2_w_TC-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_material_    |   552230c7e504e0f3fa819a46b8169bd4  17. Mr.  John Hope Franklin by Charles Ogletree.mov
2f5d941751409dfd407e8f181aa745c6    13._Ms._Jewel_Smitherman_Rogers_2_w_TC.mov                          |   933b65571efefd2ea1e642f478f4cc94  18. Dr. Olivia Hooker - Congress 03:07.mov
86841f59d7660a99feb5d3ce65c827a0    14._Ms._Thelma_Knight_w_TC-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_material_copy.mov        |   5fdea1ec2667544cb59e0a4b5b377092  19. Mr. John Hope Franklin - Congress 03:07.mov
4a0c342444fedb2096c8495fae5e1459    14._Ms._Thelma_Knight_w_TC.mov                              |   83a52017b776abd0a0c82e3866ac08b5  2.  Dr. Olivia Hooker 11:16:04.mov
d6853f5f8fda9f130073fb3e3dbf16e6    15._Mr._Robert_Holloway_w_TC-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_material_copy.mov      |   3611978acf5e564efe7567262b9960f8  20. Bill O'Brian - Historian.mov
56b0d7952f01b48f47d90a5c300411ef    15._Mr._Robert_Holloway_w_TC.mov                            |   09108415da82b24c114f3c135db611eb  21. John Rogers - Descendant.mov
eafa27fce895e52bc7b6071668e0c10f    16._Mr._Archie_Franklin_w_TC-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_material_copy.mov      |   1d74cad5bf3e0887d31c4df709b91957  22. Ms. Eddie Faye Gates - Historian 3:4:04.mov
3117d375927b0032f7b804d1f272f97a    16._Mr._Archie_Franklin_w_TC.mov                            |   d6a5dbc85ed5b60b4fc678ba9ad9672d  23. Scott Elsworth - Historian.mov
3969d4eb70bf9595bb7a3bac283fda28    17._Mr.__John_Hope_Franklin_by_Charles_Ogletree-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_    |   529a6ad514dca022836f43a780f8d1dd  24. Dr. Olivia Hooker MV 8:07.mov
552230c7e504e0f3fa819a46b8169bd4    17._Mr.__John_Hope_Franklin_by_Charles_Ogletree.mov                     |   1ca96afc9135bc73e2be7f6702469416  25. Mr. Otis Clark MV 8:07.mov
7947f017d3e0dc194dd3085c2474583f    18._Dr._Olivia_Hooker_-_Congress_03-07-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_material_    |   2bf6c9f2cc68f7e8d54b89d9585d90d9  26. Mr. Wes Young  MV 8:07.mov
933b65571efefd2ea1e642f478f4cc94    18._Dr._Olivia_Hooker_-_Congress_03-07.mov                          |   b609627fef5619d4d735f46352d0effb  27. Survivors Supreme Court 3:9:05.mov
eb837afbd180e1c9217b5cb02ca69849    19._Mr._John_Hope_Franklin_-_Congress_03-07-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_mate    |   91c74d7902d1bd4895e77c64fd163d7d  3.  Ms. Jimmie Lily Franklin 7:8:04.mov
5fdea1ec2667544cb59e0a4b5b377092    19._Mr._John_Hope_Franklin_-_Congress_03-07.mov                     |   ac6c3ac0437a93425f1b6be05c9a4914  4.  Mr. Otis Clark 3:5:04.mov
1968980fe9a3d19650fa7c3ec5507a2e    2.__Dr._Olivia_Hooker_11-16-04-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_material_copy.mov    |   978f5771c0c6a821124387ce029983c8  5.  Ms. Juanita Arnold 03:04.mov
83a52017b776abd0a0c82e3866ac08b5    2.__Dr._Olivia_Hooker_11-16-04.mov                              |   b9fc1244ffbd733f4de4e014e5bef209  6.  Ms. Eulis Jackson 03:04.mov
ada33ffb5e5e2083856f52b5709f1b31    20._Bill_O_Brian_-_Historian-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_material_copy.mov      |   f7e5822a03f8bad047b701fd5c2c6704  7.  Mr. Wes Young 3:25:04.mov
3611978acf5e564efe7567262b9960f8    20._Bill_O_Brian_-_Historian.mov                            |   1fc6342a34e1efc6b6c99225543a2900  8.  Mr. J.B. Bates 3:5:04.mov
94e6f75688705b0e0a1b73e61cb367d7    21._John_Rogers_-_Descendant-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_material_copy.mov      |   b760f9ef2c13fbdf17c56001860176b6  9.  Ms. Beatrice Campbell Webster.mov
09108415da82b24c114f3c135db611eb    21._John_Rogers_-_Descendant.mov                            <
9345c8828f917026d88592d095190556    22._Ms._Eddie_Faye_Gates_-_Historian_3-4-04-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_mate    <
1d74cad5bf3e0887d31c4df709b91957    22._Ms._Eddie_Faye_Gates_-_Historian_3-4-04.mov                     <
65772091bcc8ebc75cca81a2fa29ecf4    23._Scott_Elsworth_-_Historian-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_material_copy.mov    <
d6a5dbc85ed5b60b4fc678ba9ad9672d    23._Scott_Elsworth_-_Historian.mov                              <
dd53a3132b03327ccf1660905aca1884    24._Dr._Olivia_Hooker_MV_8-07-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_material_copy.mov     <
529a6ad514dca022836f43a780f8d1dd    24._Dr._Olivia_Hooker_MV_8-07.mov                               <
f75eb9a79e4e4fccf53d0463a1c7d520    25._Mr._Otis_Clark_MV_8-07-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_material_copy.mov        <
1ca96afc9135bc73e2be7f6702469416    25._Mr._Otis_Clark_MV_8-07.mov                              <
f992aa8cf233d306fc7cea0a32d1d1a6    26._Mr._Wes_Young__MV_8-07-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_material_copy.mov        <
2bf6c9f2cc68f7e8d54b89d9585d90d9    26._Mr._Wes_Young__MV_8-07.mov                              <
10f38ecde7590255e88529e9ba41cd06    27._Survivors_Supreme_Court_3-9-05-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_material_copy    <
b609627fef5619d4d735f46352d0effb    27._Survivors_Supreme_Court_3-9-05.mov                          <
6d566d7dbbf79652a6545e89c8a0e5a6    3.__Ms._Jimmie_Lily_Franklin_7-8-04-Apple_ProRes_422_for_Interlaced_material_cop    <
91c74d7902d1bd4895e77c64fd163d7d    3.__Ms._Jimmie_Lily_Franklin_7-8-04.mov                                                 <
```

What is the | symbol telling me? I can't find that anywhere in the diff documentation. Some of the lines match on checksums, yes, but the filenames are slightly different. For other lines, both the checksums and filenames only exist in the first file, not the second, yet in both instances the | is used.

Further down I get the < symbol, which I understand.

I don't get it.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Side-by-Side.html

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks! I couldn't find that for some reason.